# How to get to São Tomé and Príncipe?

Tags: transportation, islands, africa, sao-tome-and-principe

While browsing through Google Maps, I struck on [São Tomé e Príncipe](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Sao%20Tom%C3%A9%20en%20Principe&hl=nl&ie=UTF8&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=43.393645,88.066406&oq=sao%20tom&hnear=Sao%20Tom%C3%A9%20en%20Principe&t=m&z=9), an island country which seems like a very interesting destination. I immediately started looking for ways to get there. This seems to be very challenging. So far I only found one option, which is TAP that connects Lisbon with Sao Tome. Not only is the connection quite expensive, it is also quite infrequent (1 option in August).

How can I get to Sao Tome?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

STP Airways has a weekly flight leaving from Lisbon.

If you are willing to make a connection or fly on different date, [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Sao_Tome_and_Principe) has other options:

> Air Nigeria flies between Lagos & Sao Tome via Libreville on Tuesdays and via Douala on Thursdays. On Tuesdays TAAG Angola Airlines flies to São Tomé from Luanda (flight DT511, [3]). On Thursdays & Sundays, flight DT502 stops in Sao Tome en route to Praia, Cape Verde ([4]).

Answer (score 4):

Getting there is not obvious, but [TAP](http://www.flytap.com/) is the only reasonable option at the moment. They are indeed not really cheap and not too frequent. They have one flight per week, all-year round.

There are indeed flights to some African destinations (Gabon, Nigeria, Cabo Verde), but you will first need to get there. The flag carrier [STP](http://www.stpairways.st/) can be an option if you live near Lisbon or if you can easily get there. Beware of the quality and do some research on this topic before booking.

There are rumours that as of August 2013, there will be a flight from Paris CDG, by [XL Airways France](http://www.xlairways.fr/). However, there is no official indication on their website.

[Olimar](http://www.olimar.de/), a well-known tour operator for trips to the lusophone world, is also routing its customers through Lisbon by TAP.